# $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$ and $(f'(t),g'(t)) \neq 0$, but $\mathbb{C}[f,g]\subsetneq \mathbb{C}[t]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, resultant

Actually, the following question is a consequence of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412323/a-variation-on-abhyankar-moh-suzuki-theorem?noredirect=1#comment1056640_412323) MO question.

Recall the following result: $\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$ iff $(f'(t),g'(t))\neq 0$ and $t\mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective.

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$
satisfy the following conditions:

**(1)** $\deg(f)=\deg(g) \geq 4$.

**(2)** $f=hf_1$, $g=hg_1$, $h$ is the gcd of $f$ and $g$,
and
$\deg(h) \geq 2$ and $\deg(f_1)=\deg(g_1) \geq 2$.

**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

**(4)** $f',g'$ are not simultaneously zero.

> **Question:** Is it true that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$?

I am not able to find a counterexample or a proof.

**Remark:**
$f=t^{15}+t^2$, $g=t^{15}$ is not a counterexample,
since condition **(4)** is not satisfied.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f= (t+3)(t+2)t^2,\qquad g= (t+3)(t+2)(t+1)^2$$

- $\Bbb{C}(f/g) = 
  \Bbb{C}( t^2/(t+1)^2)$ is a quadratic subfield and $f(t)\ne f(\frac1{-2-1/t})$ so $$\Bbb{C}(f/g)\subsetneq \Bbb{C}(f/g,f)\subseteq \Bbb{C}(t)$$ from which $\Bbb{C}(f,g)=\Bbb{C}(t)$.
- [$\gcd(f',g')=1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%28+%28%28t%2B3%29%28t%2B2%29%28t%2B1%29%5E2%29%27%2C%28%28t%2B3%29%28t%2B2%29t%5E2%29%27%29)
- If $t+3\in \Bbb{C}[f,g]$ then it must be in $f \Bbb{C}[f,g]+g \Bbb{C}[f,g]$ so that $t+3$ vanishes at $-2$ which is absurd.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice.

Comment: Please, do you think there is a 'mild' condition which would imply that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$? For example, what if $f,g$ are both separable? In your example they are not. Maybe that condition does not guarantee $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$. (I remember a condition that $f',g' \in \mathbb{C}[f,g]$ but it seems too strong)

Comment: I don't think separable changes anything, try with $f=(t+3)(t+2)(t+1)t, g=(t+3)(t+2)(t-1)(t-2)$